# Can edit .less and .css file though FTP?

Tags: magento2, css, less, styles

I have several question about how to modify files in Magento2.

I only have an FTP user. Is possible to modify .less and .css files using FTP

I read something about compiling the .less, how can i do that using only FTP?

Is the compiling automatic? The system has installed grunt.

Any explanation is useful because i'm really new to this Magento system.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Do not directly change the CSS files**

You can edit the CSS files via FTP and it will reflect on the frontend, but if anyone pulls down the website and makes a change to the less files then you will lose all your changes to the CSS files.

You need to compile LESS manually so editing the files alone is not enough, if it's currently being compiled by Grunt then you can follow these instructions - http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/css-topics/css_debug.html. But I wouldn't advise compiling on a live website with Grunt.

I know some people work by compiling all the assets on a staging environment and when they deploy to the live website they'll zip up the static assets from the staging website and deploy them. It minimises downtime/deployment time and ensures the code is the way you tested.

Comment: Thanks, but i can do that grunt compilation using only FTP?

Comment: If you have SSH access to the server you can, I'm not sure how you would manage it with FTP only.

Comment: +1, i think i have at least 2 problems, one i can edit the files (.css or .less) via FTP, so maybe that is a permition's problem. And 2 i don't have access to the server to execute commands. And i try to install the site in localhost 3 times so i can have a dev environment, but i didn't succeed. 2 of the magento installation have fails, and another didn't end. =(

Comment: I'd definitely recommend setting up a local dev environment, if you have any issues the Magento 2 GitHub repo may have some fixes as there are many known issues that have workarounds. Btw, if my answer does answer your question can you please mark it as accepted by clicking on the tick icon next to it.

Comment: Yes, that's what i'm trying to do, but didn't succeed. I'm using a win 10, with xampp environment. And now is the 4 time i try but Magento get stuck in some parts =(

Comment: Ouch, I only managed to get Magento installed on Windows once. The two times since it all went wrong so I switched back to OSx

Comment: Ben, i have a question, to compile grunt though command line I have to do it from the server, right? There is not other way to compile the .less files using grunt without being in the server. Is that correct?

Comment: You could compile your static assets locally and upload them straight to `pub/static` on the server, test this before you do it on the live server though as I'm no expert on deployments.